# How can you calculate the confidence interval for a parameter that's beta distributed when you only have the mean and the standard error?

Tags: confidence-interval, beta-distribution

i have the mean and the standard error of a parameter that has a beta distribution but unsure how to calculate the 95% confidence interval. Thank you!

Comment: You can calculate the parameters of the beta distribution given the mean and standard error, then go from there.

Comment: 95% CI for what? The mean? Or one of the shape parameters?

Comment: And do you mean you have the mean & standard error of a sample?